# use Instagram Basic Display API with Static site like Hugo and localhost?

Tags: localhost, hugo, static-site, instagram-graph-api

im working on a website built With the static site generator Hugo. 
I want to display the 5 latest instagram images from my own feed but having problem with the new Instagram Basic Display API.

question:

Can i use my localhost:1313 as reference when setting the
Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, Deauthorize Callback URL and Data Deletion Request URL? if not, do i need to use a https url? got a http error when i tried against a live domain.